# To calculate the transmission through a thin film interference structure in multi-layer coating to infinite reflections need to be taken into account?

Tags: optics, interference

For a two layer structure shown below I was thinking about the transmission and reflection of light at each interface. As I consider this more and more it seems like there is an infinite number of paths that light could take through this kind of structure with each one becoming more and more unlikely. I understand how the transmission and reflection of any given interface can be determined by the Fresnel equations. I am wondering how the transmission through a structure like this is calculated. Can it be a sum of an infinite series?

[image: Trying to trace seeming infinite reflections from simple multi-layer stack]

Now that I think more about it even for a single slab of glass there would be infinite reflections with each reflection being determined by the fresnel equations. Is the transmission through a slab of glass or multi-layer structure a sum of an infinite series of these reflections?

Comment: You might extend this [Fabry- Perot analysis](http://www.physics.iitm.ac.in/~ph5060/manuals/FabryPerot) to three reflecting surfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can it be a sum of an infinite series?

If you want to treat it like that, then yes. Fortunately, this will generically be some form of a geometric series,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac{1}{1-r},
\tag 1
$$
with a factor $|r|\leq 1$ (since the reflectivities are all bounded by unity), so they can be summed exactly.

This is, of course, not a coincidence, and you can imbue the calculation in $(1)$ with physical meaning by solving the problem via

- proposing an Ansatz that contains the right types of travelling waves within each interface, with arbitrary coefficients,
- formulating the correct surface form of the Maxwell equations on the boundaries between the media, and using those to formulate an appropriate linear system for the coefficients of the travelling waves, and
- solving that linear system.

Since the answer is unique, both methods will produce the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a very wide slab "almost yes".

Note that there is a small loss for each reflection for even transparent dielectrics (they are not perfectly transparent); moreover there is a little bit of scattering each time the light wave hits one of the surfaces (which are not perfectly planar). The terms become smaller and smaller.

Think about this: the sum of an infinite number of terms may be finite, if the terms decrease "quickly enough" (I am not entering into the topic of "when it is enough" here). You may want to read about infinite series (from a book or online, the subject matter is vast ... you have to find a source that is good for you).

Another thing to think about is that the result calculated using an infinite number of reflections is very close to the result calculated using a high number of reflections; but the calculation with an "infinite number of reflections" is (it may appear strange) easier.

A way to convince yourself that the calculations may be easier for "infinite terms" is to look at the geometric series [(Wikipedia link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). How much easier varies from case to case.